# What is the process to convert a pandas object containing multiple objects into a single pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, interactive-brokers

Working with the Interactive Brokers API, my data sometimes needs to be transformed into a simple  2 dimensional data frame.  Here's a sample of the Interactive Brokers data returned from the API.  To permit Stack Overflow users to see the actual data, I tried to put it in a form that could easily be retrieved:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_dict = df.to_dict()
print (df_dict)

[5 rows x 5 columns]
{'contract': {13: Future(conId=357283192, symbol='NQ', lastTradeDateOrContractMonth='20200619', right='?', multiplier='20', exchange='GLOBEX', currency='USD', localSymbol='NQM0', tradingClass='NQ'), 14: Future(conId=357283192, symbol='NQ', lastTradeDateOrContractMonth='20200619', right='?', multiplier='20', exchange='GLOBEX', currency='USD', localSymbol='NQM0', tradingClass='NQ'), 15: Future(conId=357283192, symbol='NQ', lastTradeDateOrContractMonth='20200619', right='?', multiplier='20', exchange='GLOBEX', currency='USD', localSymbol='NQM0', tradingClass='NQ'), 16: Future(conId=357283192, symbol='NQ', lastTradeDateOrContractMonth='20200619', right='?', multiplier='20', exchange='GLOBEX', currency='USD', localSymbol='NQM0', tradingClass='NQ'), 17: Future(conId=357283192, symbol='NQ', lastTradeDateOrContractMonth='20200619', right='?', multiplier='20', exchange='GLOBEX', currency='USD', localSymbol='NQM0', tradingClass='NQ')}, 'order': {13: Order(orderId=27, clientId=400, permId=1779090364, action='SELL', totalQuantity=1.0, orderType='LMT', lmtPrice=9810.0, auxPrice=0.0, tif='DAY', ocaGroup='1779090363', ocaType=3, parentId=26, rule80A='0', openClose='', eTradeOnly=False, firmQuoteOnly=False, volatilityType=0, deltaNeutralOrderType='None', referencePriceType=0, account='DU1340125', clearingIntent='IB', adjustedOrderType='None', cashQty=0.0, dontUseAutoPriceForHedge=True), 14: Order(orderId=28, clientId=400, permId=1779090365, action='SELL', totalQuantity=1.0, orderType='STP', lmtPrice=0.0, auxPrice=9780.0, tif='DAY', ocaGroup='1779090363', ocaType=3, parentId=26, rule80A='0', trailStopPrice=9780.0, openClose='', eTradeOnly=False, firmQuoteOnly=False, volatilityType=0, deltaNeutralOrderType='None', referencePriceType=0, account='DU1340125', clearingIntent='IB', adjustedOrderType='None', cashQty=0.0, dontUseAutoPriceForHedge=True), 15: Order(orderId=19, clientId=400, permId=1779090162, action='BUY', totalQuantity=1.0, orderType='LMT', lmtPrice=9800.0, auxPrice=0.0, tif='DAY', ocaType=3, rule80A='0', openClose='', eTradeOnly=False, firmQuoteOnly=False, volatilityType=0, deltaNeutralOrderType='None', referencePriceType=0, account='DU1340125', clearingIntent='IB', adjustedOrderType='None', cashQty=0.0, dontUseAutoPriceForHedge=True), 16: Order(orderId=20, clientId=400, permId=1779090163, action='SELL', totalQuantity=1.0, orderType='LMT', lmtPrice=9810.0, auxPrice=0.0, tif='DAY', ocaGroup='1779090162', ocaType=3, parentId=19, rule80A='0', openClose='', eTradeOnly=False, firmQuoteOnly=False, volatilityType=0, deltaNeutralOrderType='None', referencePriceType=0, account='DU1340125', clearingIntent='IB', adjustedOrderType='None', cashQty=0.0, dontUseAutoPriceForHedge=True), 17: Order(orderId=21, clientId=400, permId=1779090164, action='SELL', totalQuantity=1.0, orderType='STP', lmtPrice=0.0, auxPrice=9780.0, tif='DAY', ocaGroup='1779090162', ocaType=3, parentId=19, rule80A='0', trailStopPrice=9780.0, openClose='', eTradeOnly=False, firmQuoteOnly=False, volatilityType=0, deltaNeutralOrderType='None', referencePriceType=0, account='DU1340125', clearingIntent='IB', adjustedOrderType='None', cashQty=0.0, dontUseAutoPriceForHedge=True)}, 'orderStatus': {13: OrderStatus(orderId=27, status='PreSubmitted', filled=0.0, remaining=1.0, avgFillPrice=0.0, permId=1779090364, parentId=26, lastFillPrice=0.0, clientId=400, whyHeld='child', mktCapPrice=0.0), 14: OrderStatus(orderId=28, status='PreSubmitted', filled=0.0, remaining=1.0, avgFillPrice=0.0, permId=1779090365, parentId=26, lastFillPrice=0.0, clientId=400, whyHeld='child,trigger', mktCapPrice=0.0), 15: OrderStatus(orderId=19, status='PreSubmitted', filled=0.0, remaining=1.0, avgFillPrice=0.0, permId=1779090162, parentId=0, lastFillPrice=0.0, clientId=400, whyHeld='', mktCapPrice=0.0), 16: OrderStatus(orderId=20, status='PreSubmitted', filled=0.0, remaining=1.0, avgFillPrice=0.0, permId=1779090163, parentId=19, lastFillPrice=0.0, clientId=400, whyHeld='child', mktCapPrice=0.0), 17: OrderStatus(orderId=21, status='PreSubmitted', filled=0.0, remaining=1.0, avgFillPrice=0.0, permId=1779090164, parentId=19, lastFillPrice=0.0, clientId=400, whyHeld='child,trigger', mktCapPrice=0.0)}, 'fills': {13: [], 14: [], 15: [], 16: [], 17: []}, 'log': {13: [TradeLogEntry(time=datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 6, 18, 14, 9, 366578, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), status='PreSubmitted', message='')], 14: [TradeLogEntry(time=datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 6, 18, 14, 9, 366578, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), status='PreSubmitted', message='')], 15: [TradeLogEntry(time=datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 6, 18, 14, 9, 366578, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), status='PreSubmitted', message='')], 16: [TradeLogEntry(time=datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 6, 18, 14, 9, 366578, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), status='PreSubmitted', message='')], 17: [TradeLogEntry(time=datetime.datetime(2020, 6, 6, 18, 14, 9, 374238, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), status='PreSubmitted', message='')]}}
```

I thought it would be easy for Stack Overflow users to copy/paste the data into the object `df_dict` and then return it to its original state as a pandas data frame `df` using the code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df_dict)
```

However, when I try:

```
df_dict = <insert the copy/paste data>
```

it gets a `NameError: name 'Future' is not defined` and I don't know how to fix that.  Are there any ideas on how I can extract the data to permit you to use it, so that you see what I see in my program?

Moving on, my ultimate goal is make the data look like a simple pandas data frame with appropriate column names, such as:

```
   contract.conId  contract.symbol contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth contract.exchange ...
13 357283192       NQ              20200619                              GLOBEX
14 357283192       NQ              20200619                              GLOBEX
.
.
.
```

The structure of the imported object, `df` is:

```
>>>print (df.dtypes)
contract       object
order          object
orderStatus    object
fills          object
log            object
dtype: object
```

Any ideas on solving this challenge?

Comment: I guess `Future(...)` is a constructor for class `Future`. Import the class `Future` it should work fine.

Comment: Most of your imported data structure depends on the Future object (every contract number is a Future object). You have to import or define

Answer (score 0):

You might like to use [`.to_clipboard()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_clipboard.html) for this.

Obviously some of the more complicated data types such as the `Futures` object will get converted to more general ones. Other users will not need to import those dependencies though.

Comment: I don't understand how this helps.  I moved it to my clipboard, using `.to_clipboard()` as you suggested.  If I were to paste it from my clipboard to my Stack Overflow question , what python code would I, or someone else use to get it back into the form as it exists in my program?

Comment: When using .to_clipboard(), the conversion to .csv and then back again using .read_clipboard().  It appears to change the file structure when it comes back.  I'm not  sure it's helpful in solving my problem.